# Replacing a numeric value in parenthesis in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame, lets call is bob. bob has a column called "Rate" where the factor levels are a bunch of numeric values. I want to take the value in parenthesis and replace it with their negative values. For example: (50.00) now replace it with -50.00. There are several values within the column that are in parenthesis but I'm trying to find an efficient way. I have tried 
group<-(levels(bob$Rate))

```
" gsub(\\(|\\)", "-", group)   But this changes (50.00) to -50.00- and I tried 

 gsub("\\(", "-", group)  replaces ( with -
 gsub("\\)", "", group) replaces ) with "" but it can only do one or the other not both.
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, please?

Comment: The two last replacements seem fine. Just do one after the other: `group2 <- gsub("\\(", "-", group); gsub("\\)", "", group2)`

Answer (score 2):

Use a backreference:

```
gsub("(\\()(\\d+\\.?\\d*)(\\))", 
     "-\\2", 
     c("2.1", "20", "(50)", "(7.1)"), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "2.1"  "20"   "-50"  "-7.1"
```

Comment: Is there any other efficient way to do that? I have a lot of numbers with the parenthesis in them. so instead of writing them out like how you did with c("2.1", "20", "(50)", "(7.1)"), perl = TRUE) is there any way it could just pick up which numbers have parentheses and make them negative?

Comment: @Anika I don't get the problem. You can pass any vector, e.g. a column of a data.frame instead. That's standard R functionality.